# For loop in R(no clue how stop the loop and continue with the rest of my code)

Tags: r, loops, break

I would like to stop the loop when my if condition becomes true and continue to the next lines of my code. When I run this, I get an error that the subscript i in blocks[[i]] is out of bounds. Any ideas?

```
for(i in 1:length(blocks)){
  if(length(blocks[[i]]) == 0){
    path <- path[ -i , -i]

    modes = rep("A", nrow(path))
    blocks[[i]] = NULL
  }
}
```

NOTE: I have read the help for loops, next, stop and break

Comment: try reading `help("for")` ? (you'll learn about `next` and `stop`)

Comment: not an answer, just a comment... if you did, you should have mentionned it in the question. Lots of people don't read the help and the answer to your question is indeed in the help, hence my "obvious comment"...

Comment: @JamesMarshall no need to be sarcastic. Nothing in your question shows you already tried with next/stop/break somewhere. Ask yourself if you really had described your problem. And read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: lots of people actually, you'd be surprised... Also, my comment didn't diminish your intelligence and I'm sorry if you took it this way, it only diminishes the effort spent to try and solve your problem by yourself ;-). Also, I really think you should have a look at the link provided by @Tensibai on how to ask because here, we cannot reproduce your problem, we don't know what `blocks` is and we don't know what you tried to solve your problem (which can prevent us from trying the same unworking thing...)

Comment: @JamesMarshall spend some time on SO, and you'll see. The whole planet is not smart as you, and as SO is not a free code service we expect askers to show a minimal effort trying to solve the problem and expose how they're blocked, not to ask for "Give me the code". You show none of them here. Again have a look at the How to ask page I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: i never said i am smart. May be i am the dumbest person on planet. In addition i never said to someone give me the code, this insults me. I just asked if anyone has any suggestions. Here is a place to discuss and exchange ideas and knowledge

Comment: @JamesMarshall (when talking to someone, ping them so they got a notification, and it's clearear to who you're talking). So is **NOT** a forum to discuss, it's a Q&A site aimed at fixing code problems.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't want the loop to stop when the length is 0 (as you are continuing the loop afterwards?), maybe add NULL or NA or NaN at those points with a `tryCatch()` call?

Comment: Yes i do not want to stop. I want to stop the loop and continue to the rest of my code. i will try trycatch(). Thanks

Comment: @CathG I am sorry if i was rude but i thought that when someone end up here to post something has already read the obvious thinks. In addition i am not able to provide more info of my code. When i first posted this i expressed it wrong but now i think is very clear what i wanted to solve. Moreover i am a new user at this site and a noob at R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to loop while a condition is true and exit the loop when the condition become false. So you should be using the `while` control-flow operator, not `for`.

```
i <- 1
while(i<=length(blocks) & length(blocks[[i]])!=0){
    i <- i+1
}

# check that we exited the loop because there was a zero
# and not because we went through all the blocks
if(i != length(blocks+1)) {
    path <- path[ -i , -i]
    modes = rep("A", nrow(path))
    blocks[[i]] = NULL
}
# rest of your code
```

But there's really no need for loop here.

```
# apply 'length' to every element of the list blocks 
# returns a vector containing all the lengths
all_length <- sapply(blocks, FUN=length)

# check that there is at least one zero
if(any(all_length==0)) {
    # find the indexes of the zeros in 'all_length'
    zero_length_ind <- which(all_length==0)

    # this is the index of the first zero
    i <- min(zero_length_ind)
}
```

I don't know what you want to do but if your plan is to treat all the 'i' sequentially, you may actually want to work with `zero_length_ind` and treat all your zeros at once.

For example if you want to remove all the values in `path` corresponding to zero length in `blocks`, you should directly do:

```
path <- path[-zero_length_ind,-zero_length_ind]
```

(Note that if there is no zero length element in blocks, then `zero_length_ind` will be `integer(0)` (that is, an empty integer vector) and you can't use it to index `path`. This might save you some debugging time.)

Comment: Thanx a lot for this idea!!  I would like to mention that i want to spot the first emtpy observation of my list and delete that. E.g. mylist{ c(a),c(b),c(c).......} and when c(a) = character(o) or mylist[[1]] = 0 to delete that

Comment: After running the `while` loop, `i` contains the index of the first empty observation. Beware of the case when there is no empty observation, then `i` will be `length(blocks)+1` after the loop.

Comment: But I would advise you to use the "no-loop" code which also produce the index of the first empty observation. It is much more efficient and it is bad taste to use loop in R when this can be easily avoided since base operations are vectorized. Beware of the case when there is no empty observation, you should check that all_length contains at least one zero.

Comment: You know what, I just added the tests you should make as there are really important, the code will fail otherwise. Btw if your question is answered, please mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [STOP](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html) command, the code below should work

```
    for(i in 1:length(blocks)){
        if(length(blocks[[i]]) == 0){
          path <- path[ -i , -i]

          modes = rep("A", nrow(path))
          blocks[[i]] = NULL
    `     stop("Outside bounds")


        }

      }
```

Comment: Thank you man that helped in a way. To be honest that stops the loop exactly where i want but i have lets say ten more lines after the loop and i want to find a way to continue at this lines. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble parsing your title and your description. Seems to me you don't want to stop the loop, but continue for the whole length of your object `blocks`. This could help, it should skip to the next iteration when the length is different from 0:

```
for(i in 1:length(blocks)){
  if(length(blocks[[i]]) != 0) {
    next
  } else if(length(blocks[[i]]) == 0){
    path <- path[ -i , -i]

    modes = rep("A", nrow(path))
    blocks[[i]] = NULL
  }
}
```